# ionic app with firebase issue testing in the chrome using low end mobile option

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to test my ionic app with the data option as "low-end mobile". Ideally in this mode app is still connected to the internet. however, I am getting unexpected results with error like:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: Client is offline.
Error: Error: Client is offline.
    at index.esm2017.js:11192:31
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:400:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:160:1)
    at zone.js:1318:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:620:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:520:1)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:505:1)
    at data.args.<computed> (zone.js:3063:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255:1)
    at zone.js:1162:1
    at zone.js:1178:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:400:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:25476:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:399:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:160:1)
    at zone.js:1318:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463:33)
```

The code throwing this is:

```
let nstatus = await Network.getStatus()
this.core.networkType = nstatus.connectionType
this.core.isOnline = nstatus.connected

 if(this.core.isOnline === true){
     const resp:any = await this.dataSvc.getSeedConfig()
  }
```

The code for getSeedConfig is

```
 getSeedConfig(){
    const doc = ref(this.db, 'config/seed');
    return get(doc).then((snapshot) => {
      return snapshot.val(); 
    })
  }
```